# Clang/LLVM on OSX doesn't generate AVX2 code on OSX

Tags: macos, clang++, llvm-clang, avx, avx2

I'm currently compiling multiple versions of my project, for SSE, AVX and AVX2 separately and it seems to gain a reasonable performance improvement on Windows with MSVC. But on OSX with Clang there is a difference between SSE and AVX, but the AVX2 (-mavx2) compilation seems to result in identical output as AVX (-mavx). Is that a bug or Clang cannot generate AVX2 specific code?

I'm using the newest XCode:

Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0

Comment: Are you sure your cpu supports `AVX2` ? Try doing `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.leaf7_features` and see if it shows there.

Comment: I'm sure. And even if it wouldn't, the compiler should still be able to produce AVX2 specific code. I'm trying -march=core-avx2 now, according to Intel this is the one, that should work, which is just stupid... we'll see.

Comment: Thanks! It's a chaos here really :). I so miss MSVC on OSX :). (though apparently there is MSVC now, just not sure if it includes the compiler, but definitely worth trying, it's so much better than Clang...

Comment: `-march=core-avx2` is kind of weird (but should work if it's accepted).  Still, I'd recommend using `-march=haswell` or `-march=skylake` if that's what you mean.  IDK if `core-avx2` includes FMA or not, because that's a separate CPU feature from AVX2, although both were introduced in Haswell by Intel.  (AMD has the FMA3 instruction set in Piledriver and later, but not AVX2 until Excavator and Ryzen).

Comment: Yes, clang will auto-vectorize with AVX2 unless configured to only vectorize with 128-bit operations by default / for that target.  (The equivalent of gcc's `-mprefer-avx128`, to avoid turbo reductions on some Intel CPUs, and because AMD CPUs don't gain as much from using 256b vectors).  What functions are you compiling where you expect auto-vectorization with 256-bit vectors but it's not happening?

Comment: If it's an Xcode project then use the  appropriate project setting (`[CLANG_X86_VECTOR_INSTRUCTIONS]` in the `Code Generation` section), rather than adding *ad hoc* command line switches.

Comment: Thanks! So far -march=core-avx2 is actually seem to be working, somehow, probably, not tested well yet. And it is weird indeed :). Anyways I'm a bit afraid of the haswell/skylake thingy, you know, I want to enable an instruction set, specifying the architecture like this seems a bit scary :). And what I'm doing is signal processing - lots of vectorizable loops with floats/doubles.